# Get bibliography references in text order when using `rticles::elsevier`

Tags: r, bibtex, rticles

I'm writing an article for a Elsevier journal but the the references are generated in alphabetical order and i want them listed in order of their text appearance. Here is the relevant part of my `YAML`. My `LaTex` knowledge is unfortunately very limited.

```
bibliography: bibliography.bib
linenumbers: false
numbersections: true
#classoption: preprint, 3p, authoryear
csl: vancouver-brackets.csl
#csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/elsevier-harvard
# geometry: "left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
geometry: margin = 2cm
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{setspace}
   - \doublespacing
output: 
  rticles::elsevier_article:
    keep_tex: true
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
```